# Selecting nodejs/express webserver from another webserver

Tags: node.js

I have a number of nodejs/express webserver applications and now I want to combine them.
I want to create a main webpage, where the user will click and select. I want to call it with app.js

I already have: app1.js, app2.js, app3.js running as a separate webservers with their own directory structure. They are different in many ways.

Now the sequence should be:
1) running app.js serving a main static webpage allowing user to select
2) if (user selection == 1) run app1.js

Is it possible to do it easily and if yes please give me some hints.

Jan

Comment: Do you mean that if users select the first option, all the requests are to be forwarded to the first server application(i.e. `app1.js`)?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. When the user selects option1 from the main site the first server application should run (app1.js), when the user selects option2 from the main site the second webserver application should run (app2.js) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

When using express you can combine different express instances together.

**Combining different servers on one hostname**

```
var main = express();

var static = express();
var routes = express();

main.use('/static', static);
main.use('/routes', routes);
```

**Combining different servers on multiple hostname**

```
var main = express();

var static = express();
var routes = express();

main.use(express.vhost('static.example.org', static));
main.use(express.vhost('routes.example.org', routes));
```

Comment: I actually have 3 different webservers based on nodejs/express applications to be selected to run from the main webserver by a user selection. Should I use a system call to invoke the required application (app1.js or app2.js or ...) or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Use [Child Process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to fork a new instance of the server applications.

Comment: @user3358452 invoking all servers from one node process (as shown) is not an option? If not try "child process" as mentioned but try to start the instances with a service manager like systemd.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for showing me the options. I should be able to solve it from here even with my limited knowledge. I will not go for using child processes as I see a problem with handling the user browser back button. It will need the mods in existing apps to go back to the main webserver application (I think)